# Talend with SQL function seems not to work

Tags: etl, talend, talend-mdm

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer to test my database request just before I inject this request on my Talend project.

Here is an exampl. I have a request that is working fine on SQL Developer tools but not on my Talend project.

My sql statment has a function declaration and then an select like this:

```
create or replace function updateDate(p_date varchar2) return date as
  l_date date;
  e_bad_day exception;
  pragma exception_init (e_bad_day, -1847);
begin
  begin
    -- try to convert
    l_date := to_date(p_date,'yyyymmdd');
  exception
    when e_bad_day then
      -- ignore the supplied day value and get last day of month
      l_date := last_day(to_date(substr(p_date, 1, 6), 'yyyymm'));
  end;
  return l_date;
end;
/
Select ASRF_NUMASR NIR,
ASSUR_NOASSURE NOASSURE,
ASRF_CODSEX sexe,
updateDate(ASSUR_DATNAIS) as DATE_REAL
from NORMAL_ASSUR 
UNION
Select ASRF_NUMASR NIR,
ASSUR_NOASSURE NOASSURE,
```

When i put the same text on my Talend project it's not working. It seems that it only executes my function declaration.

The exception is:

```
ORA-01003 aucune instruction analysé
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I wouldn't recommend using Talend to create/replace the updateDate function at each execution of the job, as it's better to create it beforehand in your sql developer, you can try by separating your sql script using 2 components :

The DDL part of the script goes in a `tOracleRow` :

```
"create or replace function updateDate(p_date varchar2) return date as
  l_date date;
  e_bad_day exception;
  pragma exception_init (e_bad_day, -1847);
begin
  begin
    -- try to convert
    l_date := to_date(p_date,'yyyymmdd');
  exception
    when e_bad_day then
      -- ignore the supplied day value and get last day of month
      l_date := last_day(to_date(substr(p_date, 1, 6), 'yyyymm'));
  end;
  return l_date;
end;"
```

The DML part goes in a `tOracleInput` (and setting the corresponding schema on the component)

```
"Select ASRF_NUMASR NIR,
ASSUR_NOASSURE NOASSURE,
ASRF_CODSEX sexe,
updateDate(ASSUR_DATNAIS) as DATE_REAL
from NORMAL_ASSUR 
UNION
Select ASRF_NUMASR NIR,
ASSUR_NOASSURE NOASSURE,
..."
```

And call them like this :

```
tOracleRow
   |
OnSubjobOk
   |
tOracleInput -- Main -- target
```

Comment: You have a compilation error because you are missing the enclosing quotes around your script : "create or replace function ..etc .. "

Comment: thank you yes your are right but now there is another error,

Comment: yes , i select now a connection but , the name of function nownis not regonized on toracle INput

Comment: the fuction is declared on tOracle Row but it-s not recognized on the oracle input

Comment: can you please help me , i stuck on it , i done as you miontioned , the declaration of fucntion on toracle Row and the sql statment that use that function on tOracle input, i attached new sceren shoot

Comment: Could you please check that the function is created by your Talend job ? Delete it from sql developer, run your job, then check again in sql developer if the function exists ?